# Can moderators roll back edits?

Tags: discussion, moderation

It appears someone went too far in making edits to someone else's question.

> ...someone annoyingly edited my question and removed the specifics of
>   what I was asking.

[Repairing disconnected layers with selection sets using ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25724/repairing-disconnected-layers-with-selection-sets)

If I flagged this, would a moderator be able to roll it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users with 2K+ rep should be able to roll back edits: click on the edited time stamp and choose any of the "rollback" links available from the edit history.

I rolled this question back one edit.

Comment: I re-re-rolled back the OP's latest edit since they had edited it to include the more specific information.